# Eggplant not bearing many fruit

Tags: eggplant

My first time growing eggplants. I have about 10 plants that seem to be healthy, the tallest one is almost 4 feet high. Lots of flowers in the past 6 weeks, but only 2 fruits so far.

I am in central Florida, very hot now, they need heavy watering every day. The natural soil is very sandy, I enriched this area with 5 cubic feet of garden soil.

The plants are in an isolated area, and the flowers are rather inconspicuous, maybe the pollinators aren't finding them? Should I plant some flowers next to them? Pentas do well here.

[image]

Comment: You can try to pollinate the flowers yourself, a little tap will do just like with tomatoes.